# React + Babel polyfill issue for eval() in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs, polyfills

I am working on a product booking form system with the frontend in React and we have to support IE9+. I have all the standard polyfills in (Babel, Promise, Fetch) and most things are working fine. Here's the short explanation of the problem:

- The information for which form fields to display is pulled in asynchronously via a Fetch request, in JSON format.
- We have some form fields that display conditionally, depending on the values of other fields.
- The condition rules are pulled down in the Fetch request along with everything else, in the form of an ES6 arrow function that returns true/false for whether to show the field - so for example `(student) => student === 'yes'`
- I am using eval() to run this rule whenever the field it depends on updates
- This works perfectly in modern browsers, but the function we are pulling in is not being polyfilled by Babel, so in IE the eval() is still trying to run an arrow function and crashing out

Here is the function that processes these rules:

```
processRules() {
    if (this.props.item.rules && this.props.item.rules.length > 0) { 
      const ruleset = this.props.item.rules; 
      for (let i = 0; i < ruleset.length; i++) { 
        let targetItem = this.props.fields.find((e) => e.name === ruleset[i].target); 
        if (targetItem.value) {
          let rule = ruleset[i].condition;
          let checkRule = eval(rule);
          if (checkRule(targetItem.value) === true) return ruleset[i].action;
        }
      }
    } else {
      return 'show';
    }
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to get this function to polyfill back to ES5 syntax? I have babel-plugin-transform-eval but it's not affecting this function.

(Sidenote: I know all about the issues with eval. All of them. We've very carefully considered all the security issues with eval and are happy to use it anyway.)

Comment: Can your backend not return a traditional `function` expression?

Comment: @Pointy I can look into getting this changed if absolutely necessary, but it would involve rewriting all the functions that are already in, and I'm not the one who writes them. I can do this if there's no solution but would prefer to be able to solve it on the frontend.

Comment: You would have to run those arrow functions through babel or some other ES6 parser before you try to  eval them in IE11. That said, evaling functions like that is really a bad idea for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: It should be possible to run babel client side. 
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html

Comment: @HåkenLid this is exactly what I needed, thank you!!